# Multidimensional array printing wrong values in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been struggling with a simple class representing a matrix in C++. Instead of using a multidimensional array, I've decided to use a flat array and access the values by calculating the index of the according cell by `[row * x_dim + col]`. I want to use **2D** matrices only.
Ideally, I would also create getter and setter functions, but as I am already having troubles I skipped those for now.
The main problem is, that after setting values, those values seem to be corrupted somewhere along the way as when printing them out again, I'm reading different values then what I've actually stored.
Here's the (simplified) header `MyMatrix.h`:

```
class MyMatrix{
    public:
        int x_dim, y_dim;

        float *my_matrix;

        MyMatrix(int x, int y);
        ~MyMatrix();
};
```

Here is `MyMatrix.cpp`:

```
#include "MyMatrix.h"

MyMatrix::MyMatrix(int x, int y){
    x_dim = x;
    y_dim = y;

    my_matrix = new float[x * y];
}

MyMatrix::~MyMatrix(){
    delete[] my_matrix;
}
```

Now when creating a new instance of `MyMatrix`, filling the array with ascending numbers and then printing the values again, I am getting different values for some cells in the (flat) matrix. Here's what I did:

```
#include "MyMatrix.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    MyMatrix test(3, 4);

    //filling the array in test with ascending numbers
    for(int row = 0; row < test.x_dim; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < test.y_dim; col++){
            test.my_matrix[row * test.x_dim + col] = col+1;
        }
    }


    for(int row = 0; row < test.x_dim; row++){
        std::cout << "Row " << row << ": ";
        for(int col = 0; col < test.y_dim; col++){
            std::cout  << test.my_matrix[row * test.x_dim + col] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

So what my output should look like is this:

```
Row 0: 1  2  3  4  
Row 1: 1  2  3  4  
Row 2: 1  2  3  4
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
Row 0: 1  2  3  1  
Row 1: 1  2  3  1  
Row 2: 1  2  3  4
```

As one can see, the first two rows have a **1** instead of a **4** in column 3.
I've really been struggling with identifying the underlying issue here and I can't figure it out so I would appreciate any help!
Thanks!

I am using clang version 13.0.0 on an M1 Pro and the g++ compiler.

Comment: Using `std::vector<float>` as a internal class member variable for `my_matrix` might make the implementation of that class way easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong index:

```
 row * test.x_dim + col
```

Suppose you are in the last iteration of the outer loop then `row == x_dim-1` and you get:

```
 (x_dim-1) * x_dim + col
```

while it should be (supposed `x` is rows):

```
 (y_dim-1) * x_dim + col
```

Tip: Your variable naming `col` vs `x_dim` and `row` vs `y_dim` can be made better. `x`, `x_dim` and `y`, `y_dim`  or `col`, `num_columns` and `row`, `num_rows` would be less errorprone.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, stupid mistake. `x` is rows, yes, using `row*y_dim+col` also works.